# Runtime is not ready for debugging

Tags: ios, debugging, react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I'm on macOS Sierra using react native 0.42.3:

I start my app using `react-native run-ios`, then press <kbd>Cmd-D</kbd> and I select "Debug JS Remotely". After that, a new Chrome Tab is opened, and by switching into the dev tools I see my console with every outputs so far.

The problem is: When I reload my app, *while the debugger is open*, it crashes with the infamous red screen saying "Runtime is not ready for debugging".

I found a lot of posts about debugging with react native, but nothing seems to address the problem when you try to reload it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed this seems to be a weird error that does not want to go away. Never fixed it on my mac either.

I just use this : https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger
Nowadays and it works like a charm.

I know it does not "fix" your problem, but its a really good alternative and it works like a charm.

Comment: I still encounter the same issue when locking the screen regardless of whether I use chrome or the RN-Debugger

Comment: This works for me. Thank you!

I tried all solutions/suggestions in this post but this is the only one that works in my case.

Answer (score 21):

These solutions both work:

1. **On simulator:** `Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings`
2. **On device:** Delete the app from the device and reinstalling it

(Update credit to @Form and @John)

Comment: Deleting the app from the device and reinstalling it also works (when not running in a simulator).

Comment: Thanks! It's now Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings. I did that on the simulator and my app deployed just fine.

Comment: That worked for me after it stopped working because of an Xcode update! Thanks

Comment: This is now under `Device` —> `Erase All Content and Settings...`

Comment: For the one that want to access `Erase All Content and Settings`! You can do it quickly by accessing the search bar! Slide you'll find it!  And then within it type `Erase All Content and Settings`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using WebStorm, make sure you use **debug** to start the application, not just **run**. That can also cause it.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing **CMD-D** and then choosing **Stop Remote JS Debugging** resolved the issue for me

Comment: this doesn't resolve the issue that debugging isn't working, but merely disables debugging.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, chrome window was opening multiple times when clicked on `Remote JS Debugging` in iOS simulator and I was getting following error:
[image]

I fixed this my shutting down chrome completely and restarting it. Once restarted chrome, I ran `react-native run-ios`. This fixed the issue.

Following link might be helpful as well: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6682

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the browser cache worked for me.
suggested in this issue here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6682

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, go CMD-D. On a PC, go Ctrl-D. Then choose "Reload JS Bundle".

Answer (score 0):

For me same error was happening when chrome was not installed but I guest you could verify if chrome is not installed or devtools are not installed:

[Download Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=CHBD&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8ejOusvd4wIVh-NkCh1TpQ6GEAAYASAAEgK7n_D_BwE) or `npm i -g react-devtools`

Answer (score 0):

I happened to face the same issue of cached bundle, spent one whole day to dig down the issue. Finally came up with solution

If you are in chrome browser
Chrome -> Clear Browsing Data -> Select Cached Images and files (Make sure Time range is all time)

-> Clear data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be multiple simulators running in the background and one of them is throwing this error, looking for a debugger. You can check once.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the cause for it to be actived and how to solve it easily with just I click of a button, if you of course use expo!

If you are using expo, then you might have as I, accidentally click the wrong botten instead of the other choices, which was for my case, so to fix it easily just press and hold the expo app with tree fingers or shake it will open a menu where you can select to

**"Stop Remote Dubgging"**

will solve it!:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue because I had an web client opened and an I was debugging iOS app. When the web client is closed. Everything works fine.